# How to undo the recent migration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a table **job** where I have added three new fields now I want to remove those fields from that migration.

Now the situation is : After that migration I have done few more migrations
with other tables which I do not want to touch but only want to remove the migration done on job table.

should I create one more migration which says

```
rails generate migration RemoveFieldNameFromJob field_name:datatype
```

or Is there any better way to do that like rollback option ?

Comment: the better way is to create another migration that remove these fields

Answer (score 1):

If you migrated the database after, then yes i assume the best option is to create another migration and remove the field.

Answer (score 1):

You can rollback a migration by using **STEP** or **VERSION**.

**Using STEP**

Provide the number of steps you want to rollback or skip to get the default value of 1.

```
rails db:rollback # STEP is defaulted to 1
rails db:rollback STEP=2
```

**Using VERSION**

Provide the migration version number, which is the numeric part of the migration name and stands for the UTC the migration file was generated `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`.

```
rails db:migrate:down VERSION='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

**TL;DR**

Migrations using **VERSION** are used in cases where you need to rollback only one migration and it is not the latest. Using **STEP** would mean that you need to rollback all the migration until that point, which is error-prone and possibly catastrophic.

Migrations using **STEP** are used in cases where you need to rollback one or a series of the latest migrations.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to revert the change locally, maybe because you then want to edit or remove the migration, then use

```
$ rake db:migrate:down VERSION=...
```

`VERSION` must be your migration number, for instance `20150915231214`.

If instead the migration has already been deployed, for instance to production or to any other system, then you should use another migration to revert the changes you don't want.

Comment: The migration has been deployed to staging .

Comment: Hence you should create a new migration otherwise you will increase the risk of conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to use `rails db:migrate:down`, I have faced with this kind of error:

```
$ rails db:migrate:down
rails aborted!
VERSION is required - To go down one migration, use db:rollback
```

So if you want to undo your recent migration, you should use `rails db:rollback`.